# Merge two array based on common id

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, array-merge

i have my function like this to which I am passing classid

```
  selectedSubjects;
  classnamewithid;
  subjectNameByID;

  selectClass(selectedClass) {
          

    this.selectedSubjects = this.topicWithClassSubjectList.filter(
      (topic) => topic.class_id === selectedClass
    ); // to filter out class with same id
   

    const groups = this.selectedSubjects.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      (acc[cur.subject_id] = acc[cur.subject_id] || []).push(cur.topic_name);
      return acc;
    }, {}); // to group the array according to subject
   
// checkpoint#1
    this.selectedSubjects = Object.keys(groups).map((key) => ({
      subject_id: key,
      topics: groups[key],
    }));

  }
```

my class list array is like this

```
{class_id: 1871, class_name: "1st"},
{class_id: 1872, class_name: "2nd"},
```

final array of selectedSubjects after checkpoint#1 is

```
[{"subject_id":"551","topics":["Evolution"]},{"subject_id":"711","topics":["Vector"]}]
```

What i want in selectedSubjects array is to have a subjectName associated with each subject_id. I have an array of subjectId with SubjectName as :

```
{class_id: 2711, subject_id: 551, subject_name: "Biology"}
```

i want selectedSubjects array to look something like this

[{"subject_id":"551", "subject_name":"biology", topics":["Evolution"]},{"subject_id":"711","subject_name":"science","topics":["Vector"]}]

Comment: Well, where is your subject name? Please [edit] your question to include sample data in the code, ready to run, as an [mre]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to do so. It appears as though Angular and TypeScript don't really matter to this question, and you could construct your code so that `this.` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a minimal example, I'm not entirely sure what your data looks like, but based on the description, something like this should work.

```js
const subjectsToTopics = [{
  subject_id: 551,
  topics: ["Evolution"]
}, {
  subject_id: 711,
  topics: ["Vector"]
}];
const classList = [{
    class_id: 1871,
    class_name: "1st"
  },
  {
    class_id: 1872,
    class_name: "2nd"
  },
];
const topicWithClassSubjectList = [{
    class_id: 1871,
    subject_id: 551,
    subject_name: "Biology"
  },
  {
    class_id: 1872,
    subject_id: 551,
    subject_name: "Biology"
  }
];

function selectClass(selectedClass) {
  const classnamewithid = classList.find(
    (classes) => classes.class_id === selectedClass
  ); // to get the class name and class ID of selected class

  if (classnamewithid === null) {
    throw Error(`Class with id ${selectedClass} not found`);
  }

  const selectedSubjects = topicWithClassSubjectList.filter(
    (topic) => topic.class_id === selectedClass
  ); // to filter out class with same id


  return selectedSubjects.map((subject) => ({
    subject_id: subject.subject_id,
    subject_name: subject.subject_name,
    topics: subjectsToTopics
      .filter((entry) => entry.subject_id == subject.subject_id)
      .map((entry) => entry.topics)
      .flat()
  }));
}

console.log(selectClass(1871));
console.log(selectClass(1872));
```

Note that you don't use `classnamewithid` anywhere, so you could just delete it.